# Where can I find the most recent documentation of the memcached binary protocol?

Tags: documentation, binary, memcached, protocols

I'm implementing a Memcached proxy, and need the most recent, most accurate, and most detailed memcached binary protocol docs I can find.

I already found these:

- http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/MemcacheBinaryProtocol
- http://code.sixapart.com/svn/memcached/branches/binary/server/doc/protocol-binary.txt

The problem is that the documents seem to be inconsistent with many implementations I found, and are missing messages examples which will make my life easier.

So my question is where can I find an official, up to date, and detailed (complete) documentation for the memcached binary protocol?

Any relevant links containing command messages examples are also most welcome.

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not want to use Moxi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their wiki has a more recent page on the binary protocol: http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/BinaryProtocolRevamped

Of course, there is always the [source](https://github.com/memcached/memcached) itself...

Comment: Thanks @jackrabbit. This is actually much better than what I had before. Do you have links for additional message examples?

Comment: Sorry, no. I just spent 5 minutes with google to find the above link. Never used memcached myself.